# Need help to export Vue SFC that import Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, export, vue-component

I'm trying to export a Vue SFC but i'am not sure how to export the component including the mySwiper object. I hope to see an example from someone who know-hows to do it. Below the JS part of my SFC

```
<script>
import Swiper from 'swiper'

  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {

    // Optional parameters
    direction: "horizontal",
    loop: true,

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    }

  })

export default {
    name: "Employees",    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem myself by moving the object instantiation inside the mounted property.

```
export default {
    name: "Employees",
    mounted: function() {
        let mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            direction: "horizontal",
            loop: false,
            spaceBetween: 50,
            effect: "slide"
        })
    }
}
```